# Remove Everything Befor Third Forward Slash

Tags: java, android

I have the following strings:

```
http://somedomain.com/dir/sub/folder/file.txt
```

OR

```
https://10.0.0.1/dir/sub/folder/another_folder/file.txt
```

I want to remove everything before the third forward slash (remove the domain) and still keep the third forward slash.

Expected results:

```
/dir/sub/folder/file.txt
```

OR

```
/dir/sub/folder/another_folder/file.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?limit=25&since=1374196005");
String protocol = uri.getScheme();
String server = uri.getAuthority();
String path = uri.getPath();
Set<String> args = uri.getQueryParameterNames();
String limit = uri.getQueryParameter("limit");
```

I think you need a `path` value

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`URL class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) that is what you are looking for.

> The URL class provides several methods that let you query URL objects. You can get the protocol, authority, host name, port number, path, query, filename, and reference from a URL using these accessor methods

Use this :

```
URL aURL = new URL("https://10.0.0.1/dir/sub/folder/another_folder/file.txt");
aUrl.getPath();
```

> Output result

```
path = /dir/sub/folder/another_folder/file.txt
```